# How to test if a text fragment is Quoted-printable encoded

Tags: java, encoding, mime

I am looking for a robust way in Java to test if a text fragment is [quoted-printable encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable). The most straightforward way would be to test whether a string contains char sequences which match the following regular expression: `(=[A–F0-9][A–F0-9])|(=[\r][\n])` (encoded characters + `=` and soft break for a newline).

Comment: There is no robust way of detecting this given an arbitrary string fragment,  why do you need it? Where does the text come from?

Comment: An example of a text fragment can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable#Example. I work a  email database - http://www.isi.edu/~adibi/Enron/Enron.htm. Some of the emails are quoted-printable encoded and some of them not.

Comment: The email headers indicate the encoding.

Comment: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~enron/ looks like it has the same corpus with headers.  Maybe you could get in touch with the ISI folks and point out their error, and/or explain in more detail how they (think they) cleaned up the corpus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would negate the test; text which contains = followed by anything other than newline or two hex digits is not QP; but this is still a weak heuristic - somebody could put `=3D` in unencoded text just for the heck of it (and I just did). Bottom line: if you don't know the encoding, you don't know the encoding.

Comment: I am getting slowly to the same conclusion. Thx.